# Java SWT: Group objects refuse to inherit their background from their parent (shell)

Tags: java, swt

About a year ago, I wrote a small Checkers game as part of some study assignment. The code files was laying around on a flash drive ever since, and recently I decided to revive it and make it better, just to fill up my spare time.
I wrote it using SWT, and I remember that back then it worked perfectly.
Oddly enough, after setting all the environment again (This is a new computer, so I had to install Eclipse, import SWT jar files, etc...), and running it, I was surprised to find out that the some Group objects - that were holding buttons - were not properly displayed.

Let me first post the code, and I'll explain exactly what I'm talking about (it's quite long, so I omitted irrelevant parts)...

```
public class MainMenu {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainMenu menu=new MainMenu();
        menu.run();
    }

    /*private class StartGameListener extends MouseAdapter {
         // omitted because it is not relevant, unless it is, and then I wouldn't mind posting it too...
    }*/


    final static String images_path="./images";

    final private Display display;
    final private Shell shell;  
    private Button start_game;
    private Button quit_game;
    private Button[] mode_options;
    private Button[] board_options;
    private Text player_one_name;
    private Text player_two_name;

    private BoardPanel board;
    private CustomBoard custom_board_menu;
    private IController game_controller;

    //constructor
    public MainMenu() {

        /******************
         * main shell setup
         ******************/
        display=new Display();
        shell=new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
        shell.setText("Checkers Game");
        Image menu_background=new Image(display, images_path+"/backgrounds/menu.jpg");
        shell.setBackgroundImage(menu_background);
        shell.setBounds(menu_background.getBounds());
        shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT); 


        /******************************************
         * Start Game and Quit game button
         ******************************************/
        start_game=new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        start_game.setText("Start Game");
        start_game.setLocation(650, 135);
        start_game.pack();
        start_game.addMouseListener(new StartGameListener());

        quit_game=new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        quit_game.setText("Quit Game");
        quit_game.setLocation(650, 170);
        quit_game.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
                shell.dispose();
                display.dispose();
            }

        });
        quit_game.pack();


        /******************
         * game modes Group
         ******************/
        Group game_modes=new Group(shell,SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);
        game_modes.setText("Game Mode");
        game_modes.setLocation(65, 120);
        game_modes.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

        mode_options=new Button[5];
        mode_options[0]=new Button(game_modes, SWT.RADIO);
        mode_options[1]=new Button(game_modes, SWT.RADIO);
        mode_options[2]=new Button(game_modes, SWT.RADIO);
        mode_options[3]=new Button(game_modes, SWT.CHECK);
        mode_options[4]=new Button(game_modes, SWT.CHECK);

        mode_options[0].setText("Versus Mode");
        mode_options[0].setLocation(5, 20);
        mode_options[0].setSelection(true);
        mode_options[0].setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        mode_options[0].pack();

        mode_options[1].setText("PC Mode");
        mode_options[1].setLocation(5, 45);
        mode_options[1].setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        mode_options[1].pack();

        mode_options[2].setText("Demo Game");
        mode_options[2].setLocation(5, 70);
        mode_options[2].setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        mode_options[2].pack();

        mode_options[3].setText("Creatures");
        mode_options[3].setLocation(130, 70);
        mode_options[3].setEnabled(false);
        mode_options[3].setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        mode_options[3].pack();

        mode_options[4].setText("Custom Game");
        mode_options[4].setLocation(130, 20);
        mode_options[4].setSelection(false);
        mode_options[4].setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        mode_options[4].pack();


        /*********************************************
         * the following anonymous class will listen to any
         * change in the game modes selection and will
         * react accordingly
         *********************************************/
        MouseAdapter modes_listener=new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
                String selection=((Button)e.getSource()).getText();
                switch (selection) {
                    case "Versus Mode":
                        player_one_name.setEnabled(true);
                        player_two_name.setEnabled(true);
                        mode_options[3].setEnabled(false);
                        mode_options[4].setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    case "PC Mode":
                        player_one_name.setEnabled(true);
                        player_two_name.setEnabled(false);
                        mode_options[3].setEnabled(false);
                        mode_options[4].setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    case "Demo Game":
                        player_one_name.setEnabled(false);
                        player_two_name.setEnabled(false);
                        mode_options[3].setEnabled(true);
                        mode_options[4].setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                }
            }

        };

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            mode_options[i].addMouseListener(modes_listener);
        }


        /******************
         * board size Group
         ******************/
        Group board_size=new Group(shell, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);
        board_size.setText("Board Size");
        board_size.setLocation(65, 230);
        board_size.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

        board_options=new Button[2];
        board_options[0]=new Button(board_size, SWT.RADIO);
        board_options[1]=new Button(board_size, SWT.RADIO);

        board_options[0].setText("Normal");
        board_options[0].setLocation(5, 20);
        board_options[0].setSelection(true);
        board_options[0].setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        board_options[0].pack();

        board_options[1].setText("Large");
        board_options[1].setLocation(5, 45);
        board_options[1].setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        board_options[1].pack();


        /********************
         * players names Group
         ********************/
        Group players_names=new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
        players_names.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));
        players_names.setLocation(335, 130);
        players_names.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

        Label player_one=new Label(players_names, SWT.LEFT);
        player_one.setText("Player 1 Name: ");
        player_one.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        player_one_name=new Text(players_names, SWT.BORDER);
        player_one_name.setText("Player 1");
        player_one_name.setLayoutData(new GridData(128, SWT.DEFAULT));

        Label player_two=new Label(players_names, SWT.LEFT);
        player_two.setText("Player 2 Name: ");
        player_two.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        player_two_name=new Text(players_names, SWT.BORDER);
        player_two_name.setText("Player 2");
        player_two_name.setLayoutData(new GridData(128, SWT.DEFAULT));

        game_modes.pack();
        board_size.pack();
        players_names.pack();
    }//end of MainMenu constructor


    //render the main menu
    public void run() {

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code produces this:
[image]

As you can see, the Group widgets (and also both the Start Game and Quit Game buttons) have no transparent background (which is what I'd expect, had they inherit their background from their parent - the shell). 
Again, this is strange, because I remember that a year ago this wasn't a problem, but nevertheless, I tried to change:

```
shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
```

To:

```
shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
```

But this didn't help much:

[image]

The ones with the keen eye must have noticed that now the Start Game and Quit Game buttons are more neatly displayed, but still - the three Group objects would not agree to inherit their background from their parent (although the widgets inside them [radio buttons, text labels, etc...] do).

Does anyone know what can be the problem? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The [Whats New for Eclipse 4.5M5](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/) says that transparent backgrounds are new in that release.

Comment: Woo-hoo! I used SWT 4.5M1 instead of SWT 4.4.2 and now it is correctly displayed, without me even changing anything in my code... I guess it was some compatibility issue.